# How to set the local cpp source path in Android studio for prebuild library

Tags: android, debugging, native, prebuild

I created an App which includes our source code as a native lib (so-file). I'm able to step into it and everything works fine so far with this code.

This native lib links against another native lib which was pre-build on a different machine and which I copied into the jni-abi-folder. I have checked out the svn-repository of this so-file in a different folder parallel to my project and need to be able to debug also into it.

When I now do a break, I can see the method names in the callstack so I assume that the symbols can be loaded, but Android Studio doesn't know where to find the source files.

Under Visual Studio, when I did a break, I could specify the symbols in the symbol path and then an error was displaced that I should navigate to the corresponding source file. Then I only needed to navigate to the folder and it was working.

How can this be done with Android Studio - I have the newest version 3.2.1 installed.

Comment: No one an idea how to specify a source search path for external libraries in Android Studio (lldb maybe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

1. I got a stripped version from my colleague, he basically gave me the version inside his apk which is stripped. Now he gave me directly the build version (I think it is located somewhere in the intermediate directory or so, just search for the name of the lib).
2. Under Run\Edit Configurations\Debugger\LLDB startup commands the original source directory can be mapped to the source directory on my computer which is different. To achieve this, enter "settings set target.source-map or-dir cur-dir"

There should be a way to find out the original source directory from the so file, but I don't know it right now.

I hope this can help somebody else

Comment: You can use `llvm-dwarfdump` to find the original source dir from the so file. (if it dumps too much info, use the `-n` option to look up the symbol you specifically need)